# awk NR==FNR for file matching, what went wrong?

Tags: linux, unix, awk

I have two files that I'd like to find rows that matches in column 1,4,5,6 and sometimes 5,6 column can be switched and that should be allowed.

Here's the format of the two files:
file1

```
1   1:10177 0   10177   AC  A
1   1:10352 0   10352   TA  T
1   1:14930 0   14930   G   A
1   1:15211 0   15211   T   G
1   1:15274 0   15274   G   A
```

file2

```
1   1:10177:A:AC    0   10177   AC  A
1   1:10235:T:TA    0   10235   TA  T
1   1:10352:T:TA    0   10352   TA  T
1   1:10616:CCGCCGTTGCAAAGGCGCGCCG:C    0   10616   C   CCGCCGTTGCAAAGGCGCGCCG
1   1:10642:G:A 0   10642   A   G
```

As you can see that there rows matched for column 1, 4, 5, and 6.

The awk line that I have is the following:

```
awk 'NR==FNR {chr[$2]=$1; pos[$2]=$4; a1[$2]=$5; a2[$2]=$6} NR>FNR && ($2 in chr) && chr[$2]==$1 && pos[$2]==$4 && (a1[$2]==$5 && a2[$2]==$6 || a1[$2]==$6 && a2[$2]==$5) {print $2}' file1 file2 > extract_results.txt
```

Can anyone help me understand what went wrong? Thanks very much!!

Comment: `$2` in file 2 has values like `1:10177:A;AC` that do not appear in column 2 of file 1.  The prefix of `$2` in file 2 appears, but not the whole value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you haven't showed your expected output, so based on your query I have written this code.

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$1,$4,$5,$6];b[$1,$4,$6,$5];next} (($1,$4,$5,$6) in a) || (($1,$4,$6,$5) in b) ' Input_file1  Input_file2
```

***EDIT:*** As per OP's requirement we need to get 2nd field as output so putting this code as follows too.

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$1,$4,$5,$6];b[$1,$4,$6,$5];next} (($1,$4,$5,$6) in a) || (($1,$4,$6,$5) in b){print $2}'   Input_file1   Input_file2
```

In case you want to take output into a output file then change `print $2` to `print $2 > "output_file"` in above code too.

***EDIT2:*** Though it is NOT efficient code, since OP is learning and asked for fix for OP's code so putting it here.

```
awk 'NR==FNR {chr[$1]; pos[$4]; a1[$5]; a2[$6];next} ($1 in chr) && ($4 in pos) && ((($5 in a1) && ($6 in a2)) || (($6 in a1) && ($5 in a2))){print $2}' file1 file2
```

Comment: Thanks, I see that you use file2 content as output. That's great. I am thinking to output only column 2 of file 2 actually but I can do that separately from the output file I guess. Do you know what went wrong in my original method? I am trying to read the O'Reilly book and do this.. which isn't particularly efficient :P

Comment: @Molly_K, please check my EDIT code for getting the 2nd field of file2 as output, let me check your code(though for huge files it could be an issue with memory since your code is using lot of arrays).

Comment: @Molly_K, ok Molly. Your code was having lot of bugs like you are assigning many arrays to check 1,2,4,6 fields are present in other file or not(which could be done in a single array like I did), then no need to assign them value only the field's index will be enough. your key of all arrays was $2 which was messy too. I have added EDIT2 in my solution to provide a kind of fix for your code, please go through it and let me know if this helps you?

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 : pluse-uno for, as always, a well written answer AND for tech support. Good luck to all.

Comment: Thank you @RavinderSingh13. It's very helpful. I will avoid using multiple arrays in the future. I do have huge files so it was not ideal as you observed. Thanks very much for the comments :)

Comment: @Molly_K, your welcome, glad to help. Keep learning and keep sharing knowledge, cheers :)